# Check if key is already pressed when loading new page (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keylistener, keydown

I'm currently building a site which makes use of a custom quick navigation via JavaScript.

If the user presses the Right Key, he'll be navigated to the next page in my page list, and by pressing ALT + Right or Left Key, he can navigate forward and backward through his browser history.

This is my current code:

```
var map = [];

    window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function(e){
        e = e || event; // to deal with IE
        map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

        if (map[18] && map[39]) { // ALT + Right
            window.history.forward();
        }
        else if (map[18] && map[37]) { // ALT + Left
            window.history.back();
        }
        else if (map[39]) { // Right Key
            window.location.href = "{{ path('sctn_findsong') }}";
        }
        if (map[38]){ // Up Key
            //
        }
        if (map[40]){ // Down Key
            //
        }
    }
```

It all works fine, except for one little issue:
Let's say I want to go three pages back - if I'm a logically thinking human being, I'll first press ALT + Left to go back one site, then when I'm on the previous site just keep ALT pressed and press Left again to get back one more site. However, when I go back one site and keep ALT pressed, it doesn't register that ALT is still pressed, so I have to press ALT again each time I reach a previous site, which is pretty annoying.
How do I get it to work the way I want it to?
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You need an event "keyup" or "keydown" to be able to know the state of your ALT key after a new page loads. However you can store the state (boolean down or up) in localStorage for example. When a new page loads you can read the value. However this may not be reliable especially if you release the key during a page load (before the page is loaded). Also you need to include your javascript that deals with the keyevents/localStorage in every page that loads.

Have you considered changing the design of your webapp so the content of your pages will get loaded through asynchronous (ajax) requests? This way you actually don't leave the main page and can keep track of the events fired. The downside is that you need to create your own "history" as you actually don't leave a page from the browser perspective. A good way to do this is by making use of `window.location.hash`.

Comment: Thank you. I have a Plan B on solving my problem, which is basically what you've mentioned in your second paragraph, but I was just hoping I had overlooked something obvious and that it would be a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can load pages to `IFRAME` if you don't wanna use *AJAX*

Answer (score -1):

you should look for e.altKey==true to see if alt key is down

```
var map = [];

window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event; // to deal with IE
    map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

    if(e.altKey==true){ // ALT down
    if (map[39]) { //  + Right
        window.history.forward();
        //console.log("forward");
    }
    else if (map[37]) { //  + Left
        window.history.back();
        //console.log("back");
    }
    }


    else if (map[39]) { // Right Key
        window.location.href = "{{ path('sctn_findsong') }}";
    }
    if (map[38]){ // Up Key
        //
    }
    if (map[40]){ // Down Key
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this under right before the first if-Statement: if (e.AltKey == true) { map[18] = true; } - is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: e.AltKey is not the same as map[18] see updates snippet